# How to choose the attributes of a @property in a nutshell?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, properties, interface-builder, lifecycle

**How to quickly know which attribute to add to a `@property` ?**

I got it for `@property (strong)` and `@property (weak)`, I think : `strong` if the class "owns" the referred-to instance ; `weak` if it is just a reference to an object whose existence is not managed to our current class.

If the property is created by dragging-and-dropping from Interface Builder, sometimes there is the cryptic `unretain_unsafe` or so. It sounds so complicated to me, but I believe Xcode knows what it does...

- I also kind of understand that `retain`, `assign` are kind of deprecated...
- And that it is better (compulsory) to use `copy` for `NSString` attributes...
- But what if I want to have a `@property` to an `int` or an `enum` ?
- Shall I choose the `weak` attribute if my `@property` points to a singleton ?

You see : **so many questions for theses attributes !**

*I thought it would be nice to have a short and clear explanation of these attributes as some members here do :)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few notes in no particular order

- `weak` has the additional features of being nil-ed out when the referred-to object is deallocated, so you are never left with a dangling pointer to garbage
- It is not compulsory to use `copy` semantics with an `NSString` property, but it is highly recommended. While `NSString` is immutable, your property might be set to a mutable string subclass, so if you don't want it changing out from under you, you should use `copy`
- The rule of thumb for scalar property types is pretty simple: they are not reference counted, so neither `strong` nor `weak` applies. But they can be `readonly` or `readwrite`, depending on what you need.

Comment: So : for scalar properties, I can (should) put no property. I guess it is equivalent to `readwrite`. Thanks for your answer, it is nice points (I didn't know them, esp. point 1 and 2) !!

Comment: @Colas: They should still be properties, but you should not choose any ownership behavior (strong/weak/copy), since there is no ownership to be had. `readwrite` is a different issue, which is whether the property can be changed or not, and is a valid choice to make for all properties.

Comment: I would add that `copy` should be used for any and all copyable objects, not just strings.

Comment: @PeterHosey : Sorry, I meant "for scalar properties, I can put no attribute". I guess `@property int myInt` is equivalent to `@property  (readwrite) int myInt`. Thanks !

Comment: @Colas: That's true, but IMHO stating it explicitly makes things more readable, especially if others are using your codebase and might be surprised by the read/write semantics.